# Does pyqt have to be main thread?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 to build a GUI on top of an existing program. The existing program has it's own driver file and I would like to collect user inputs from the interface from said driver. The issue is I cannot get around using `sys.exit()` which ends the program.

Here is the function I would like to use to display the GUI for a user:

```
 def gui():
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
     ui = Ui_MainWindow()
     ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
     MainWindow.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
     return ui.argv
```

My `Ui_MainWindow` class has an instance argv that holds all the user input entered in through the interface. I want to import my `gui()` as a module into my driver and do something like `usr_input = gui()`. Of course, the code above will terminate before returning the variable `usr_input` because of the `sys.exit()` call.

I am well aware that it would work to call my driver from the gui to begin the program; for example, a button action could include the calling the driver.  However, this is at best unaesthetic and at worst highly annoying structure: I want driver to be the main thread of my program whether or not I am using command line interface or my custom GUI.

I also tried removing the `sys.exit(app.exec_())` call and changing it to `app.exec()`, but in this case the GUI window never opens...

So how do I get around the fact that `sys.exit()` terminates the entire program while still getting the GUI window to show up and function properly?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `app.exec_()` or `app.exec()`? I can't see a reason why the former wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, `app.exec_()` will work with both python 2 and python 3, but `app.exec()` will not work with python 2, because `exec` is a keyword in that version. So it looks like the OP is using python 2, and is probably masking the error with a bare try/except.